# Can't find hidden input element in iFrame on website using Puppeteer and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, puppeteer

I am trying to enter a value into an (specified in the code) input, but puppeteer cannot find the selector. The input type is hidden and it can successfully find every other element on the page, except for the input fields. Edit: I've recently found that the input form is in and iFrame too.

I am using [[image]puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)

I've tried using the following:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="checkout[credit_card][vault]"]', el => el.value = '000000');
```

and:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="number"]', el => el.value = 'Bob');
```

and both end up with an error saying no element/selector found.

I also tried using `page.type();`

The html look like this:

```
<input 
  value="false" 
  size="30" 
  type="hidden" 
  name="checkout[credit_card][vault]" 
  id="checkout_credit_card_vault">
```

and like this

```
<input 
  autocomplete="cc-number" 
  id="number" 
  name="number" 
  type="tel" 
  aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number"
  data-current-field="number" 
  class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-22" 
  placeholder="Card number">
```

These are two different pieces of code in the HTML where I'm trying to enter the value into the input form.

I believe they relate to the same input field somehow, but I am not sure. Still new to programming...

Comment: Does the input field maybe not exist at that point in time? You could try [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) before calling `page.$eval`.

Comment: Did you try just doing it using the id? Or is there more than 1 field you need to fill in?

Comment: I just found out an important factor... The form is in an iFrame, so how would I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an element inside an `iframe` you first have to find the frame and get its content frame via [`elementHandle.contentFrame`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe). This will return a [`Frame`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#class-frame) object which has similar functions like the `page` itself. You can use the [`frame.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#frameevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) which works like the `page.$eval` function (but inside the frame).

**Code sample**

```js
const iframeHandle = await page.$('iframe#id-of-your-iframe'); // Change the selector
const frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.$eval(/* ... */);
// ...
```

**Minor improvements**

Apart from that, your code should work. I would only recommend to use better selectors in your code. It is always the best to use the [ID selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) if possible, as the ID is unique on the page:

- Replace `input[name="checkout[credit_card][vault]"]` with `input#checkout_credit_card_vault`
- Replace `input[name="number"]` with `input#number`